# Changing URL in internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I need to change the URL in IE8 without reloading the page. 
There is a method window.history.pushState, this method does not work in IE8 but it works in other version.

is there any method to change the URL in IE8 without reloading the page.

Comment: Nope, the history API is part of HTML5 and is [not supported in IE8 or IE9](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate)

Comment: I need one in IE8, is there anyone?

Comment: Refer to my previous comment: **no, there is not**

Answer (score 1):

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/hashchange), IE8 supports using the `hashchange` event. This event allows you to to trigger a function when the part after the hash in a URL is changed, effectively running when the URL is changed. A change in the hash of a URL also does not refresh the page.

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    if(location.hash == "#foo") {
        alert('bar');
    }
}
```

More information on the hashchange event can be found at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange).

Answer (score 0):

As @Bojangles suggested that is not possible in IE8/9 but then you could use hashed segments in your URL to reload your pages to a different page via AJAX requests which I suspect you are trying to do.

e.g. http://www.example.com/#a, 
     http://www.example.com/#b

hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
window.location   = "url"
```

try using this

Comment: The OP wants to change the URL _without_ reloading the page, _a la_ the HTML5 History API